# Where is a detailed list of operating systems supported by GitHub' s Electron?

Tags: github, software-distribution, electron

Where is a detailed list of operating systems supported by GitHub' s Electron? Researched but cannot find anything. Can someone point me to some docs? A user reported he can not install on freeBSD. So it seems there are limitations when using electron-prebuilt.

Comment: [There is now](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/supported-platforms.md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to find one for Electron, but here is the one from Atom

https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/master/README.md#building

Atom is made using Electron so ideally these are the supported platforms

Answer (score -1):

From http://electron.atom.io/:

> Electron apps build and run on Mac, Windows, and Linux.